# Handling composer install command in Travis CI environment to speed up the build time

Tags: symfony, composer-php, travis-ci

I successfully created an example .travis.yml file and the build passes. However, it is a bit slow. The main cause is composer install and it takes up to 40 seconds.

Since my experience with Travis CI is 2 days old, I need someone with experience to tell me what is the better practise when it comes to using `composer install` in Travis environment? Under what block I should call it and what should be the command itself?

**Note:** I use Symfony projects so if there is something specific to this framework, please let me know.

I read some blog posts and went through example files in some open source projects and ended up confusing myself. Some use under `before_script:` and some `install:` etc. Also some use `composer install`, `composer install --prefer-source --no-interaction --dev`, `travis_retry composer install --ignore-platform-reqs --no-interaction --prefer-source` so on. My aim is to speed up the build time.

- [What's wrong with composer and your .travis.yml?](http://till.klampaeckel.de/blog/archives/204-Whats-wrong-with-composer-and-your-.travis.yml.html)
- [Composer update without PHP environment checking](https://hannesvdvreken.com/2015/01/18/composer-ignore-platform-reqs-flag/)
- [PHP and Continuous Integration with Travis CI](https://www.sitepoint.com/php-continuous-integration-travis-ci/)
- so on

**My own .travis.yml.**

```
language: php

php:
  - 5.6

env:
  global:
    - SOURCE_DIR=src

install:
  - sudo apt-get update > /dev/null
  - sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-fastcgi > /dev/null

before_script:
  - ...
  - ...
  - composer self-update
  - composer install
  - ...
  - ...

script:
  - bin/phpspec run --no-ansi --format=dot
  - bin/behat --profile=default -f progress
  - ...
  - ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no one right answer for which section the `composer install` belongs to IMO. Use what makes sense for you. I would put it in `install`.

Prefixing it with `travis_retry` is also a good idea if the command is prone to fail due to network issues. for example. It'll retry the same command a default number of 3 times. The command is only considered a failure if after all retry attempts the wrapped command still did not `exit 0`.

As for speeding up you build, I wouldn't bother for eliminating 40s from the build time. That said, you can have a look at caching the composer install directory. This would save a tarball of that dir after the builder finishes and try to get it from network storage at the beginning of the next build. That way only new.changed dependencies would be needed to install. Since that archive lives on network storage and not inside the container however, this might just not give you any actual speedup. [Docs for caching](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/)

Comment: Looks like I have to `sudo: false` to use caching feature but I'm using `sudo` for some commands so as I far as I understand caching composer directory (`$HOME/.composer/cache`) doesn't seem as a solution for me. Also, I often change composer.json&lock files so my build would break if Travis reads from the old cache. Build depends on new packages etc.

Comment: The docs probably aren't up to date anymore in that respect https://blog.travis-ci.com/2016-05-03-caches-are-coming-to-everyone

Comment: I now have 30% faster build after enabling cache. Thank you for the link and info.